# Javascript Object Prototype TypeError: ... is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, jquery-deferred

I'm have a problem with calling the method in the prototype, which returns:

> TypeError: this.backgroundImagesReplace(...) is undefined
>
> this.backgroundImagesReplace(data)

My code looks like the following:

```
var Template = function() {};

Template.prototype = {

    backgroundImagesReplace : function(data) {

        var defer = $.Deferred();

        // some code that resolves the deferred object
        defer.resolve(data);

    },

    replace : function(data, callback) {

        this.backgroundImagesReplace(data)
            .done(this.replaceContent)
            .done(this.replaceElement)
            .done(this.replaceAttribute)
            .done(systemObject.executeCallBack(callback));

    },

    init : function() {

        this.replace([], function() {

            console.log('here');

        });

    }

};

var TemplateObject = new Template();
TemplateObject.init();
```

Any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten to return the object in your `backgroundImagesReplace` function. While you could return the `Deferred` object directly, it would be advisable to return a `Promise` object instead, as that's more suitable for passing to other objects/functions. `Deferred` objects should be kept private as their state can be directly changed, while it is much more difficult to accidentally change the state through a `Promise` object. You can do that by doing the following:

```
backgroundImagesReplace : function(data) {

    var defer = $.Deferred();

    // some code that resolves the deferred object
    defer.resolve(data);

    return defer.promise();
},
```

This gives you that `TypeError` as your code is attempting to access a property of `undefined`, which (of course) will not do what you expected it to do.

Comment: you need to return `defer.promise()`

Comment: Thanks Qantas - that was it!

Comment: @ArunPJohny: true -- while returning the `Deferred` object directly "works", returning a `Promise` instead is probably better to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your method backgroundImagesReplace does not return anything. So the *result* of calling it is undefined, on which you are trying to call `.done()`.